# Machine Learning gradient descent clarification

Tags: machine-learning

I was watching Andrew Ng's CS229 ML lectures on youtube and i noticed something when he was explaining gradient descent using contour plots.[contour plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8b0j.png)

He's showing what theta gets updated to at each iteration of gradient descent. He says that it always goes in a direction orthogonal to the rings. In the image, it shows that the optimal value for $\theta_0$ is around 25, we started at around $30$. He explains that in linear regression the cost function looks like some sort of bowl and it has one global minimum. I'm just wondering given how we update $\theta_0$, how is it possible that in the first iteration $\theta_0$ goes further away from the minimum (from $30$ to $>30$). If we update $\theta_0$ based on its gradient, how does it go further away from the minimum?

Comment: Think about what gradient descent is doing

Comment: In my head, when I plot the cost function with respect to theta0 and theta1, gradient descent checks the partial derivatives and goes towards that direction. The final direction that it moves is a sum of the two directions above. I just can't imagine a scenario where it would go away from the minimum in any direction.

Comment: $f(x+h)=f(x)+h^T\nabla f(x)+o(\|h\|)$. Now think about how gradient descent works

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: The idea behind gradient descent is choosing $h$ in the above equation to minimize $f(x+h)$. What is problematic is that the above equation describes a qualitative local relationship. Indeed, all it says it that if $h$ is small enough, then $f(x+h)<f(x)$. It doesn't say how small $h$ actually needs to be.